# Speech Recognition Game - Unity

Tags: c#, performance, unity-game-engine, speech-recognition, delay

Good Afternoon everyone,

I am currently working on a uni project on accessibility in video games. My game uses eye tracking and speech recognition. It consists of 2 small level : a shooting game and a running level. The game i offline. The Eye tracking part works fine but I encountered an issue with the speech recognition. I am using the phrase recognizer from unity speech: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/develop/unity/voice-input-in-unity .

The problem is that there is a delay of a second to a second and a half from the moment I speak to the recognition. It happens before my onphrase recognizer is called (before my functions are called). The delay is still present when I take down wifi and cortana and I am wondering if there is any way to shorten it as it is pretty bad in a video game...

Here is the code in question:

```
 //Speech recognition Initialization
private KeywordRecognizer keywordRecognizer;
private Dictionary<string, System.Action> actions = new Dictionary<string, System.Action>();

[...]

void Start()
{
//we add the jump function to the dictionnary
actions.Add("jump", () => Up(1.25f));

//we set the speech recognition function and start it
keywordRecognizer = new KeywordRecognizer(actions.Keys.ToArray(), ConfidenceLevel.Low);
keywordRecognizer.OnPhraseRecognized += RecognizedSpeech;
keywordRecognizer.Start();
}

private void RecognizedSpeech(PhraseRecognizedEventArgs speech)
{
Debug.LogWarning("jump");
actions[speech.text].Invoke();
}

public void EndListening()
{
actions.Clear();
//keywordRecognizer.Stop();
}

[...]"
```

Would anyone have a lead or an advice or is working/ has worked on something similar ?
Thank you for your time.

Comment: Probably depends a lot on your phrases you want to recognize.. i don't think you can make it a lot faster .. it will need time to process the input

Comment: The phrase is simply "jump" as this works like a dictionary for actions. I lowered the confidence that lowers a tiny bit the delay but also let's pass some similar sound like "up" "ump". Anyway, thank you for your answer. Hoping maybe someone has something or at least I would've tried my best !